# Woocommerce - Multiple banking accounts

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've a wordpress/woocommerce application with two checkout pages. Now I offer Paypal and Sofortueberweisung as payment gateways to my customers. The thing is that I would like to send the money to a particular banking account, depending on the checkout page. 
Problematic is that I can input only one project id in the woocommerce backend corresponding to one banking account. Do I have to install a second wordpress/ woocommerce application to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is in the same situation: Installing a separate wordpress instance is definitely the cleanest solution to achieve this kind of goal.
Keep in mind that you have to buy a separate licence for Sofortueberweisung.